# What is wrong with this? (sqlite3)

Tags: python, sql, select, sqlite, operationalerror

```
recordCheck = c.execute("SELECT * FROM Student, Behaviour WHERE Forename=:oldForename, Surname=:oldSurname,     YearGroup=:oldYearGroup, FormNumber=:oldFormNumber, Date=:oldDate, BehaviourType=:oldBehaviourType", {"oldForename":oldForename,    "oldSurname":oldSurname, "oldYearGroup":oldYearGroup, "oldFormNumber":oldFormNumber,"oldDate":oldDate,"oldBehaviourType":oldBehaviourType})
```

This returns this error:

```
OperationalError: near ",": syntax error
```

But I can't see what is wrong with it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comma is not valid in a `where` clause.  Conditions are normally separated by `AND` or `OR`.  So, this is invalid:

```
WHERE Forename=:oldForename, Surname=:oldSurname
```

One of these would be valid:

```
WHERE Forename=:oldForename AND Surname=:oldSurname

WHERE Forename=:oldForename OR Surname=:oldSurname
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I have amended that but still receive the same error when trying to run it

Comment: Can anybody help with this?

Comment: @Jambofun . . . Did you change *all* the commas?

Comment: Updated, same error: c.execute("UPDATE Student, Behaviour SET Forename=:newForename, Surname=:newSurname, YearGroup=:newYearGroup, FormNumber=:newFormNumber, Date:=newDate, BehaviourType=:newBehaviourType WHERE Forename=:oldForename AND Surname=:oldSurname AND YearGroup=:oldYearGroup AND FormNumber=:oldFormNumber AND Date=:oldDate", {"newForename":newForename, "newSurname":newSurname, "newYearGroup":newYearGroup, "newFormNumber":newFormNumber, "newDate":newDate, "oldForename":oldForename, "oldSurname":oldSurname, "oldYearGroup":oldYearGroup, "oldFormNumber":oldFormNumber, "oldDate":oldDate})

Comment: @Jambofun . . . That is an entirely different question, because it is an `update` statement but the OP is a `select` statement.  You should ask another question.  However, SQLite does not support multi-table updates.

Answer (score 0):

Use `WHERE X=Y AND Y=Z` not `WHERE X=Y, Y=Z`

```
recordCheck = c.execute("SELECT * FROM Student, Behaviour WHERE Forename=:oldForename AND Surname=:oldSurname AND YearGroup=:oldYearGroup AND FormNumber=:oldFormNumber AND Date=:oldDate AND BehaviourType=:oldBehaviourType", {"oldForename":oldForename,    "oldSurname":oldSurname, "oldYearGroup":oldYearGroup, "oldFormNumber":oldFormNumber,"oldDate":oldDate,"oldBehaviourType":oldBehaviourType})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using commas in the WHERE clause and you should use AND's.